# How to calculate direction from initial point and another point?

Tags: geometry

I'm making a simple game where I shoot things from a certain point on screen (A).

I tap the screen and shoot the projectile from initial point(A) to the tap point(B).

But I want the projectile to move along the same path instead and fly out of bounds of the screen.

How do I calculate a point that is on the same line that these two points, but further away?

This is a simple math, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 12):

If A and B are both 2D vectors, then...

```
direction = normalize(B - A)
any point on the line = direction * distance + A
```

Or you can just take `normalize(B - A) * speed` and add that to the projectile's position every frame.

Answer (score 2):

The equation of a line is `y=mx+b`  where `m` is the slope, `b` is the offset, and `x` and `y` are variables (coordinates on the grid).

To get this equation from 2 points, you can use the [point-slope formula](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/strtlneq2.htm):

```
y - A.y = m(x - A.x)
```

To calculate the slope, `m`, you need to figure out the change in y values over the change in x values:

```
(B.y-A.y)/(B.x-A.x) = m
```

To get the offset, `b`, you need to plug in the slope and simplify the formula:

```
y = m*x - m*A.x + A.y
```

So `b = m*A.x + A.y`

After you have `m` and `b`, you have the equation for the line.  Plug in x and y values and it will be on that line.